# How to work with Google Colab efficiently?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I try to train a neural network on Colab using a GPU there. I am now wondering if I am on the right pave and if all the steps I am doing are necessary, because the process I am following does not appear very efficient to me.

```
# Install the PyDrive wrapper & import libraries.
# This only needs to be done once per notebook.
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
# This only needs to be done once per notebook.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

import os

# choose a local (colab) directory to store the data.
local_root_path = os.path.expanduser("~/data")
try:
  os.makedirs(local_root_path)
except: pass

def ListFolder(google_drive_id, destination):
  file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'%s' in parents and trashed=false" % google_drive_id}).GetList()
  counter = 0
  for f in file_list:
    # If it is a directory then, create the dicrectory and upload the file inside it
    if f['mimeType']=='application/vnd.google-apps.folder': 
      folder_path = os.path.join(destination, f['title'])
      os.makedirs(folder_path)
      print('creating directory {}'.format(folder_path))
      ListFolder(f['id'], folder_path)
    else:
      fname = os.path.join(destination, f['title'])
      f_ = drive.CreateFile({'id': f['id']})
      f_.GetContentFile(fname)
      counter += 1
  print('{} files were uploaded in {}'.format(counter, destination))

ListFolder("1s1Ks_Gf_cW-F-RwXFjBu96svbmqiXB0o", local_root_path)
```

This commands allow to connect the Notebook in Colab with my Google Drive and stores the data in Colab. Because I have a lot of images (more than 180k) the storage of the data in Colab takes very, very long and partially the connection breaks. I am now wondering if it is necessray to upload all the data from my Google Drive to Colab?

If no, what do I have to do instead to work with the data from Google Drive? 
If yes, is there a way to do this more efficiently?
Or is there maybe a completely different way I should work with Colab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access files directly on your Google drive without copying them into Notebook environment.
Execute this code in one cell:

```
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

And try:

```
!ls /content/gdrive
```

Now you can copy your files from/to */content/gdrive* directory and they will appear in your Google Drive.

Comment: And from there it is relatively easy to create a process that loads a small buffer of images into the instance's memory so that to the main process training the NN it will appear as though all of the images are readily available in the instance's memory.

Comment: Thank you! That means, I don't have to run all the code I ran before?

Comment: Yes, you just need to mount gdrive and provide absolute path to your images under _/content/gdrive_ dir to your dataset loader